# How do we setup Retries for SQS - Dead Letter Queue in spring framework using JMS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I have a Spring Boot + Gradle Project using JMS for consumer and I am using SQS for queue and DLQ. The consumer is annotated with `@JmsListener`, and I want it to send the failed message to SQS dead letter queue. How can I do it? Is there anything like Retriable and Non Retriable Exception in JMS?

Comment: From a JMS perspective you'd normally force a redelivery attempt by the broker by using a transacted session and calling `rollback()`. Then, based on the broker's configuration, the message would be put into a DLQ after the maximum delivery attempts had been reached.

However, Amazon SQS only implements [a subset](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/supported-implementations.html) of the JMS specification which apparently doesn't include the `SESSION_TRANSACTED` acknowledgement mode.

JMS doesn't have "Retriable" and "Non Retriable" exceptions.